# Communication between 3 Atmega controllers

Tags: avr, communication

I am studying a bio chemistry analyzer, in which there are Main controller, printer board controller and detector board. To establish communication between these three, RxD pin of one controller is connected to same (RxD) of others and same with TxD (all ic's TxD is interconnected.

Is this type of communication possible (Normally we connect TxD to RxD and vice versa)? How they are communicating then? Which protocol is used (I2C,SPI or USART).

How will be master and slave configuration?

Comment: If you connect all the txds to all the rxds and disable all but one txd output at a time in software in accordance with a taking turns protocol, it will work.  Basically (and as far as the software is concerned) you would have something like rs485, but without the differential transceivers.

Comment: I have found that sometimes `RxD` and `TxD` are labeled inconsistently; on the master `TxD` could mean "this is the pin on which data is transmitted," but on the slaves `TxD` could mean "this is the pin on which the transmitted data is ingested."  I have gotten my lines crossed more than once due to this...

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say.  If these TXD and RXD pins are really dedicated to RS232 serial, then there would be a multi-driver conflict with the TXD pins.  Also, they would not be able to talk to each other.

There are a couple of possibilities, though.  I2C, CAN, and half duplex RS-485 are all shared busses that are connected in this way, though the pins are not TX and RX.  In I2C you have clock and data.  In CAN and RS-485, you have a single differential pair for the data.  It's also possible they are using a UART, but they would have to have some method of crossing over TX and RX.  Possibly they are disabling the UART on the transmitter end, turning the RX pin around, and bit-banging it.  Or perhaps the microcontrollers can swap the TX and RX pins.  Or perhaps what you said is not correct and the controller TXD is connected to RXD on the others, and vise-versa, with the TXD pins disabled when not transmitting to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Thanks.. Alex for reply...These are port pins also .... Is this a single line communication?

Comment: I have no idea.  What controllers are they, specifically?  Unless you can look at how the pins are configured internally or you can stick a logic analyzer on the connection, it's really hard to say.

Comment: How to check on DSO for communication between controller...what signal can I check?

Comment: Probe the pins.  See if it looks like a standard protocol.  If so, see if you can figure out the bit rate.  If the scope supports it, try turning on serial decode and testing some combinations of parameters.

Comment: But if it is used as I2C interface then there must be pull up resistor in this case. But in my application, 4.7 k resistor is connected only at RxD pin of all three controllers ( not for TxD ). Is I2C communication possible without resistor at TxD?

Comment: SPI can also be used in multi-master mode, but it's a bit more work than just banging out the bits.

Comment: are you sure TXD and RXD are not all connected to a single node?

Comment: You can confirm or reject that in about 10 seconds with a multimeter - just see if TXD and RXD on one chip are shorted to each other.  It's possible, but it would mean that the chips would have to continuously tristate the TX pin so they can don't step on each other.

Comment: Continuously tri-stating the TXD pin, expect when it is your turn to talk, is pretty much how shared busses work - the only real difference is that often in those cases you are controlling an external line driver to operate or tri-state, rather than the MCU's own transmit pin, but conceptually it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen systems where RXD and TXD are all connected to a single node but only one TXD pin in the system is enabled at any time.it's not RS-232, it operates at UART voltages, CCTalk is one example of this setup.

Comment: You're right. edited.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you'd do that, but definitely I2C is an option. Most mirocontrollers nowadays have plenty of I2C libraries and peripheral implementation documentation in their resources.

Another thing you could try doing is multiplexing, so you choose only one of the 3 lines as a valid one for whatever you're communicating to.

In any case, I understand that you didn't design that but that you're only studying it right? Have in mind that communication can follow standard protocols (I2C, RS232, SPI, etc...) or you can just make your own so it all depends on how the controllers are programmed. For instance, if the three TxD are all interconnected (properly pulled up or down, and connected through buffers or resistors) but thanks to the programming only ONE can actively pull the line's voltage Up or Down, then it would work.

Try studying the data-flow a bit more, like what should be happening inside those processors and how should they be "talking" to each other, and then we can help out more